# connection refused error while registering grpc-gateway handler running on localhost

Tags: go, grpc, grpc-gateway

I am trying to add grpc-gateway to my grpc based service. Here is some code from my `main.go` file

```
// NewGRPCServer method is an abstraction defined in my codebase
// that essentially calls https://pkg.go.dev/google.golang.org/grpc#NewServer
// and does some additional stuff
gRPCServer := servers.NewGRPCServer(&servers.NewGRPCServerOpts{
    Addr: config.GRPCAddr,
})
grpcServer := gRPCServer.GetUnderlyingServer()
api.RegisterXXXServer(grpcServer, s)

var wg sync.WaitGroup

wg.Add(1)
go func() {
    defer wg.Done()
    // this Run method is just an abstraction over grpc.Serve() method
    // that calls net.Listen and grpc.Server.Serve method
    gRPCServer.Run(ctx)
}()

proxyMux := grpc_gateway.NewServeMux()
err = api.RegisterXXXHandlerFromEndpoint(ctx, proxyMux, config.GRPCAddr, []grpc.DialOption{grpc.WithInsecure()})
if err != nil {
    l.Panicf("Not able to start HTTP proxy server: %s", err)
}
```

I keep getting this error when I run the server  `[core]grpc: addrConn.createTransport failed to connect to {127.0.0.1:20201 127.0.0.1:20201 <nil> 0 <nil>}. Err: connection error: desc = "transport: Error while dialing dial tcp 127.0.0.1:20201: connect: connection refused". Reconnecting...`

I checked out other SO questions and GH issues related to this but they didn't solve my problem and were mostly about either IPV6 or some misconfiguration.

Comment: I'd guess that `RegisterXXXHandlerFromEndpoint` is getting called before `gRPCServer.Run` brings the server up (not unexpected given you call `gRPCServer.Run(ctx)` in a goroutine).  Note that a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would make it easier to help.

Comment: On top of what Brits mentioned, you haven't explained how/where the socket listen happens.  This is important, because it is perfectly fine to Listen before spinning off the Serve goroutine and letting that race with a connect, as the kernel will buffer the incoming socket while waiting for the Accept for a period of time.

Comment: oh sorry about that, socket Listen happens inside of `Run` method, will update the post